# PHP If else and some logics

Tags: php, if-statement

I just having some problem of if/else or somewhat logical things in here, I have a fullcalendar that shows all the date that being reserve, I limit the reserve by 5 per date, but when I having a 2 or more reserved on the date and having reserve by other date, It gives me the same result as 4.

```
global $db;
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM reserve_master
          INNER JOIN reserve_details
          on reserve_master.reserve_id = reserve_details.reserve_id
          INNER JOIN reserve_indicator
          on reserve_master.reserve_id = reserve_indicator.reserve_id
          WHERE reserve_indicator.touserid = '$id'
          AND reserve_master.type = 'Repair' ";

$res = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$count = 5 - $count;//count the available slot
$date_changed = "";
$reserve_id = 0;

foreach ($res as $row) 
{
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

    $current_timestamp = strtotime($row["dateend"] . '+1 day');

    $time = date("Y/m/d",$current_timestamp);


    if($row["datestart"] == $date_changed)
    {
      //This is for avoiding repeating graph on fullcalendar
    }
    else
    {
        if(empty($count))
        {
            $count = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            $count;
        }

        $data[] = array(
            'id'    => $row["reserve_id"],
            'title' => $count,
            'start' => $row["datestart"],
            'end' => $time,
            'color' =>getColor($row["status"])
                );
        $date_changed = $row["datestart"];
        $reserve_id = $row["reserve_id"];
    }

}

        echo json_encode($data);
```

[This is image of the error with captions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQwup.png)

Database

```
CREATE TABLE `reserve_master` (
`reserve_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datestart` date NOT NULL,
`dateend` date NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`reserve_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin

CREATE TABLE `reserve_indicator` (
    `indicator_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `reserve_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `touserid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `byuserid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`indicator_id`),
    KEY `reserve_id` (`reserve_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `reserve_indicator_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reserve_id`) REFERENCES `reserve_master` (`reserve_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `reserve_details` (
 `details_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `reserve_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`details_id`),
 KEY `reserve_id` (`reserve_id`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `reserve_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reserve_id`) REFERENCES `reserve_master` (`reserve_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

All i had tried is to get the right available on the 2nd of febuary 2018 and not the others.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is mess, I'm very sorry;

Problem is solved already;

I use eventLimit on fullcalendar and set it to 1

Count = 5 not subtracted by the num_rows

and few set on if-statement

Few answer I used rows and res as it is easy to indicate for results and rows, and i used it same as other queries.

Thank you.